# Subquery IN statement collection

Tags: objective-c, realm

```
NSArray *sectionNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"aa", @"bb", nil];

RLMResults<Department *> *filteredDepartments = [Department objectsWhere:
                                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(sections, $section,  $section.name IN %@).@count > 0",[NSArray arrayWithArray:sectionNames]]];
```

This is Department model.

```
@interface Department : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;

@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<Section> *sections;

@end
```

I have this error. sectionsNames is the name array of section object.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(sections, $section,  $section.name IN (
)).@count > 0"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `NSString`'s string interpolation via `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, you should use `NSPredicate`'s argument substitution support:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(sections, $section, $section.name IN %@).@count > 0", sectionNames];
RLMResults<Department *> *filteredDepartments = [Department objectsWithPredicate:predicate];
```

Since this is such a common pattern, Realm provides a wrapper that takes care of constructing the `NSPredicate` for you, in the form of `+[RLMObject objectsWhere:]`:

```
RLMResults<Department *> *filteredDepartments = [Department objectsWhere:@"SUBQUERY(sections, $section, $section.name IN %@).@count > 0", sectionNames];
```

`NSString`'s interpolation inserts a string representation of the variable into the string. The string representation of your array is `(aa, bb)`, which is [not valid in an `NSPredicate` format string](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html). Using `NSPredicate`'s argument substitution  substitutes the *object* into the predicate without needing to worry about whether the string representation matches what `NSPredicate` expects.

Comment: it works and thanks for your answer.  But I think something is wrong. In my section array list there is 3 sub departments. 2 subdepartments belongs to "A Department" and one subdepartment belongs to "B Department" .  but after in the filtereddepartments array it only returns "A Department". how can i trace this error?

Comment: It's difficult to tell without more information. I'd suggest posting a new question with more details so people can help you with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890556/subquery-and-in-statement-in-realm    I asked again. please help me check. what is wrong. thanks you so much.